# Process32First is not returning TRUE even if process is running

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

I am trying to find the process running and killing it from my application.
Below is my code.

```
bool ProcessKill()
 {
    PROCESSENTRY32 process;
    Logger::getInstance()->test(L" checking the call kill status");
    ZeroMemory(&process, sizeof(process));
    process.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);

    HANDLE snapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, NULL);
      if( snapshot == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE )
        {
        Logger::getInstance()->test( TEXT(" CreateToolhelp32Snapshot (of processes)") );
        return( FALSE );
        }
    Logger::getInstance()->test(L" checking the call kill status 2222");
    if (Process32First(snapshot, & process) != FALSE)
        {
            Logger::getInstance()->test(L"checking the kill status");
                while(Process32Next(snapshot, &process) == TRUE)
                    { Logger::getInstance()->test(L"1111");
                        if (wcsicmp(process.szExeFile, L"kill.exe") == 0)
                            {  
                                Logger::getInstance()->test(L"found kill running");
                                HANDLE hProcess_Name = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, process.th32ProcessID);
                                DWORD dwRet = ::WaitForSingleObject(hProcess_Name, 5000);
                                if (dwRet == WAIT_OBJECT_0)
                                dwRet = ERROR_SUCCESS;
                                //Logger::getInstance()->test(L"kill is running");
                                else
                                    {
                                        ::TerminateProcess(hProcess_Name, 1);
                                        ::CloseHandle(hProcess_Name);
                                        Logger::getInstance()->test(L"kill is terminated");
                                        CloseHandle(snapshot);
                                        return 1;

                                    }

                            }
                    }
    }
    else
    {
        Logger::getInstance()->test(L" Process32First the call kill status 333");
    }
    CloseHandle(snapshot);
    return 0;
}
```

What I am observing that Process32First is failing it is returning false.
Can any one let me know what is the reason behind the failure and how it can be fixed. Any work around for this.

Comment: Improve your error reporting, display the value returned by GetLastError().

Comment: Thanks @HansPassant i checked the GetLastError(). It is returning 24 value which means The program issued a command but the command length is incorrect. but what is the reason for this how it can be corrected.

Comment: I'll randomly guess you are running a 32-bit program on a 64-bit operating system.  Build the x64 version instead.

Comment: @iggy: Which function is reporting error 24 - `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot()` or `Process32First()`?  Please show your actual error handling. Also, if `Process32First()` did happen to succeed, you would ignore the first process in the list, as you are calling `Process32Next()` prematurely. Do not call it until after you have looked at the data that `Process32First()` returns first. Change your `while` loop into a `do/while` loop.

Comment: Process32First() is showing error 24. I am adding the code below. if (Process32First(snapshot, & process) != FALSE)
   {
    Logger::getInstance()->test(L"checking the kill status");
     while(Process32Next(snapshot, &process) == TRUE)
      { Logger::getInstance()->test(L"1111");
       
      }
  }
  else
  {
   dwError = ::GetLastError () ;
   Logger::getInstance()->test(L"Process32First the call kill status 333...." + Convert::NumToString(dwError));
  }

Comment: @HansPassant yes it is 32 bit application. Test Machine is 64 bit. We need in 32 bit buils only. Is there any work around other then building it in x64. Same code in the same machine runs some time correctly.

Comment: Well, just ignore it then and keep calling Process32Next().  Your code is buggy btw, you'll completely miss kill.exe if it happens to be the first one.

Comment: I just replaced my above code to other location in the project and it is working as expected. @HansPassant what ever changes you suggested i added that also.

Answer (score 2):

Add bellow statement before  `if (Process32First(snapshot, & process) != FALSE)` :

```
pe32.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32W);
```

***As said in MSDN :***

`tagPROCESSENTRY32` struct :

```
typedef struct tagPROCESSENTRY32 {
  DWORD     dwSize;
  DWORD     cntUsage;
  DWORD     th32ProcessID;
  ULONG_PTR th32DefaultHeapID;
  DWORD     th32ModuleID;
  DWORD     cntThreads;
  DWORD     th32ParentProcessID;
  LONG      pcPriClassBase;
  DWORD     dwFlags;
  CHAR      szExeFile[MAX_PATH];
} PROCESSENTRY32;
```

<kbd>dwSize</kbd>

Before calling the `Process32First` function, set this member to `sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32)`. If you do not initialize `dwSize`, `Process32First` fails.